# gen pathname within loadChildren of @angular/router

Tags: angular, routes

I am using lazy loading with loadChildren where I can have different pages with same similar url. Sample of how I separate it below:

```
{
    path:  ':any',
    loadChildren: () => {
        if(window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf('/some')==0){
            return import('some/path.module').then(m => m.Module)
        }else{
            return import('some/other/path.module').then(m => m.Module)
        }
    }
}
```

and the problem which I face is when I load this page directly, everything works as expected, but if I was on other page and use local redirect, in `window.location.pathname` we have the previous url.
Is there a Angular way to pull new url within the `loadChildren`?
Perhaps, it's possible somehow to hold the `loadChildren` with some kind of timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one way to solve it is to use a `canLoad` guard.

```js
// Inside your `canLoad` guard
 constructor (private router: Router) { }

 canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]) {
    if (cond1...) {
     this.router.navigate([urlForModule1]) 
   } else {
     this.router.navigate([urlForModule2]) 
  }
 }
```

You will still have to define the routes inside the parent routing module.

```js
{ path: 'some/module', canLoad: [canLoadModule], loadChildren: () => ... },
{ path: 'some/other/module', canLoad: [canLoadModule], loadChildren: () => ... }
```

Comment: so, this is the hold thinking, as been testing different case scenarios on this without success. `window.location.pathname` is not changing until we change page, with canLoad, we disable change, so that value is not changing.

Comment: in fact `segments[0].path` give correct path, which can be used in `loadChildren` and use correct module, so this can be used as answer, thank you.